# How to change the array in order to make the desired JSON object in PHP?

Tags: php, json, decode, encode

I've an array titled `$request` as follows :

```
Array
(
    [invite_emails] => suka@gmail.com, swat@gmail.com
    [page_id] => 322
    [ws_url] => http://app.knockknot.com/api/group/sendInvitation
)
```

After using `json_encode($request)` I got following output:

```
{
  "invite_emails": "suka@gmail.com, swat@gmail.com",
  "page_id": "322",
  "ws_url": "http://app.knockknot.com/api/group/sendInvitation"
}
```

But actually I want the JSON object as follows :

```
{
  "page_id": 322,
  "invite_emails": [
    "suka@gmail.com",
    "swat@gmail.com"
  ],
  "ws_url": "http://app.knockknot.com/api/group/sendInvitation"
}
```

How should I manipulate the array in PHP in order to get the above desired JSON object?

Please someone help me.

Comment: Show your PHP creating the object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : $request['invite_emails'] = $email_list;
                $request['page_id'] = $pageId;
                $request['ws_url'] = $this->mWSBaseUrl.'group/sendInvitation';

Comment: To improve the question, use the "edit" link, not comments. The problem lies in code you haven't shown, though: How do you create `$email_list`? *That's* what you want to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the list of emails using the comma:

```
$array["invite_emails"] = preg_split("#\s*,\s*#", $array["invite_emails"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer using callback functions for readability and possibilities. To your purpose, [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) should fit:

```
<?php
// reproducing array
$request = array(
        "invite_emails" => "suka@gmail.com, swat@gmail.com",
        "page_id" => 322,
        "ws_url" => "http://app.knockknot.com/api/group/sendInvitation"
);

// callback finds a comma-separated string and explodes it...
array_walk($request, function (&$v,$k) {if ($k == 'invite_emails') $v = explode(", ", $v);});
// ... and then encode it to JSON
json_encode($request);

// testing
print_r($request);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
  "invite_emails":[
      "suka@gmail.com",
      "swat@gmail.com"
  ],
  "page_id":322,
  "ws_url":"http://app.knockknot.com/api/group/sendInvitation"
}
```

You are free to change the field if your needs changes, and even suppress it to be used with any field of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP explode for example:

```
$array['invite_emails'] = explode(',',$array['invite_emails']);
```

To avoid spaces use preg_split ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)):

```
$array['invite_emails'] = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $array['invite_emails']);
```

Comment: your going to end up with a space at the beginning of the second email with this

Comment: Such *leviathanic* solution for a small problem, huh?

Answer (score -1):

This entry:

```
[invite_emails] => suka@gmail.com, swat@gmail.com
```

should be an array (currently, it is a string) in PHP, then in JSON it will look like you want it.

Comment: Well pointed, thus slightly redundant to OP question. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Well, i just answered the question ("How should I manipulate the array in PHP in order to get the above desired JSON object?"). He should change the string with an array.
Okay, it would be better to know, how this array entry "invite_emails" is created. Then i can answer how to do it better.

Comment: I'm not questioning if it's incorrect, but if it's useful.